# When and How the pointer arithmetic evaluate?

Tags: c, pointers, variable-length-array

I always took pointer arithmetic for granted. But some times it bugs me, what compiler exactly does, and when do they get evaluated? Consider the program below:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int prng(void);

int main()
{
    int x = prng(); // Pseudo Random Generator.

    int (*a)[x];

    a = malloc(sizeof(int) * 2 * x);    // Allocate 2 rows of x columned vectors

    printf("%p %p\n", a, a + 1);    // How and When does a + 1 evaluate ?

    return 0;
}
```

I am almost certain that the compiler (or program at runtime) won't ask the CPU to add `a` and `1` like normal integers for evaluating `a+1`. So how does the compiler (or program) manage to get the correct addresses?

Comment: `ptr + n` adds n *steps* to ptr. Each *step* has size `sizeof *ptr`. In your example `a + 1` adds 1 *step* of size `sizeof *a == sizeof (int[x]) == x * sizeof (int)`

Comment: It is evaluated at runtime as well as `sizeof(x)` when `x` is a VLA

Comment: @pmg Does compiler substitute ``x * sizeof (int)`` in the place of ``1`` in ``a+1``?

Comment: I don't know how the compiler does it.

Comment: @MohithReddy if you really want to know how the compiler does it, look at the generated assembly output, but you shouldn't care.

Answer (score 0):

> So how does the compiler (or program) manage to get the correct addresses?

`a + 1` is evaluated at run time.

At run time, the size of `*a` is `x * sizeof(int)`.

The sum is formed by adding to `a`, `x` `int`s to it.

---

Note:

`int (*a)[x];` is UB when `x <= 0`.

`a + 1` is UB when allocation fails.